# Export data from table in Pervasive

Tags: c#, pervasive

I want to export data from table programatically. And i wonder if it's even possible? The picture is from Pervasive, that the db-server I'm using. Please assist! :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to export data programmatically through the "Export Data" wizard in the Pervasive Control Center.
You would need to either write or have written an export module.